# When can java.nio.buffer.flip() throw NullPointerException?

Tags: java

I have a multithreaded application where the code is trying to read data from a File and then persist it in ByteBuffer via FileChannel.

It works fine for most of the time but sometimes fails with

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
```

I found that this exception occurs during **buffer.flip()**. Here flip is done before reading the data from buffer.

**Code snippet**

```
buffer.clear();
int count = channel.read(buffer, position);
buffer.flip();
```

So wanted to know in which scenario this occurs? Is it because some data might be null in file which is causing this issue or it is something related to multithread?

Comment: As far as I can tell, only when the `buffer` itself is null.

Comment: Presumably the `buffer` variable is null.

Comment: I would look further down the stacktrace, to identify what *your* code is doing in order to get to that place.

Comment: if buffer is null then, shouldn't it throw only NPE? Why is it throwing ConcurrentExecutionException?

Comment: Beware with line numbers and IDEs. Are you sure the exception comes from the flip() method, and not from the clear() one?

Comment: Yes it is at flip. buffer is a member variable. can that cause issue? since it is accessed by other threads? should it be ThreadLocal?

Comment: Can it be made a local variable in your `report` method?  Accessing the same buffer from multiple threads is probably risky (even if they use different variables to do that).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a funky custom subclass of `Buffer`, the `flip` method just changes 3 integer valued fields of the `XxxBuffer` object.   That can't generate an NPE, even if there are threading or memory coherency issues.

This means that the NPE must be happening because you are invoking `flip()` on a `null` reference.

---

> Is it because some data might be null in file which is causing this issue or it is something related to multi-threading?

No and no.

---

*UPDATE*

```
buffer.clear();
int count = channel.read(buffer, position);
buffer.flip();
```

If `buffer` was already `null`, you would get an NPE in the first line.  Otherwise, the only way that `buffer.flip()` is causing an NPE is if some other thread modifies<sup>1</sup> the `buffer` variable.

<sup>1 - The modification could happen while this thread is blocked in `read`, or it could conceivably happen before then if this is a memory coherency problem.  For example, if it is caused by delayed flushing of writes made by another thread.</sup>

Comment: buffer.clear();
int count = channel.read(buffer, position);
buffer.flip(); - This is the code snippet.. So if buffer is null, I feel it should fail during "buffer.clear". Or can there be a possibility of buffer getting null after "channel.read"?

Comment: Nothing in that code will cause `buffer` to become `null`.  Can you be sure that some other thread isn't changing `buffer`?   Is the buffer variable visible to other threads?

Comment: Will be adding code snippet in the question as well.

Comment: buffer is a class member variable.

Comment: So it could be visible to / updated by other threads.

Comment: Should buffer be made ThreadLocal?

Comment: I can't answer that.  It depends on your application's overall design.  Another possibility would be to make it an instance variable.